# Navigation by kinect, Point Cloud to Laser Scan

Tags: navigation, kinect, laser, scan, pointcloud-to-laserscan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I would like to navigate a Pioneer 3DX robot by Kinect sensor. It seems, that the simplest way to accomplish my goal is to convert PointCloud msgs to LaserScan msgs. I've launched 3dsensor.launch from turtlebot_bringup package to do the conversion. (ROS - Hydro, Ubuntu 13.10)

1. The problem is, 3dsensor.launch publishes no msgs on /scan topic.
2. What should I do next to accomplish navigation and get around obstacles?

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/99396/navigation-by-kinect,-point-cloud-to-laser-scan/) by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on ROS Answers with karma: 66 on 2013-11-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2013-11-10**:
which version of ROS are you using ?

**Comment by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on 2013-11-10**:
ROS - Hydro, Ubuntu 13.10

**Comment by [sudhanshu_mittal](https://answers.ros.org/users/5307/sudhanshu_mittal/) on 2013-11-10**:
did you check your rostopic list after running the launch file ? Does it show "/scan" topic ?

**Comment by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on 2013-11-10**:
Yes, but echo /scan is empty. I think the problem is,  http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan subscribes topics: /image & /camera_info, but openni_launch publishes msgs on /camera/rgb/camera_color & /camera/rgb/camera_info.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There seems to be a pointcloud_to_laserscan stack. Haven't used it myself, but might be worth a try.

Best regards
Christoph

---

Originally posted by [Christoph](https://answers.ros.org/users/6836/christoph/) with karma: 96 on 2013-11-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Wojciech](https://answers.ros.org/users/7006/wojciech/) on 2013-11-10**:
Yes, there is http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan but it subscribes:
/image & /camera_info, and openni_launch publish msgs on /camera/rgb/camera_color & /camera/rgb/camera_info. Is there simple way to change subscribed topics?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-11-18**:
Use topic remapping. see http://wiki.ros.org/Remapping%20Arguments for more info.